# Loop map with entity

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Have some for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++){
            List<NomenclatureTypeFirst> nmtf = nomenclatureTypeFirstService.getAllByRequest(ids.get(i));
            map.put(ids.get(i), nmtf);
        }
```

Tried to uset th:text on value like this:

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="entry, stats : ${map}">
        <td th:text="${entry.key}"></td>
        <td th:text="${entry.value.detname}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But catch:

```
Property or field 'detname' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your `entry.value` is of type `List<NomenclatureTypeFirst>`, which means you need to use an index like `<td th:text="${entry.value[0].detname}"></td>`  or change your data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your map is a list, so you have to iterate over the values:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="entry, stats : ${map}">
    <td th:text="${entry.key}"></td>
    <table>
      <tr th:each="value : ${entry.value}">
         <td th:text="${value.detname}"></td>
      </tr></table>

    </tr>
</table>
```